# rails search box with $.ajax method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

how to create an search box using rails so that i can fetch data dynamically using $.ajax method

My code is :-

```
<%= form_for '/search' do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :source, :class => 'form-control', id: 'from' %>

 <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>

// source is city names
```

how to call ajax here and how it going to render to controller and back with result please give me an idea how this works i could not  able to find proper illustration for this

Comment: <%= form_for '/search' do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :source, :class => 'form-control', id: 'from' %>

 <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>

Answer (score 0):

Ok maybe this can help you:

1)

```
# config/application.rb

class Application < Rails::Application
    config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = true
    # [...]
end
```

2)

```
<%= form_for '/search', remote: true do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :source, :class => 'form-control', id: 'from' %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

3) In your controller action

```
def search
  Model.where(name: params[:source])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to '/search' }
    format.js  
  end
end
```

4)Then create a search.js.erb

```
Your js here
```